# What is meant by a Bilinear Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to understand what is meant by a bilinear form. It seems to be some constraint on a map of two vectors to a field. I would be grateful if someone could give me a very trivial specific (as in non-abstract) example of what is, and isn't a bilinear form. I find examples more insightful than definitions.

What use are bilinear forms?

Comment: The dot product between two vectors is a simple example of a bilinear form.

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Bilinear_map

Comment: and for example $f(x,y) = xy^2$  for $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ **is not** bilinear.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks, that's the kind of trivial example I was after.

Comment: So bilinear forms are functions of two variables that are in some sense linear and they are analogous to linear functions of one variable, is that the general idea?

Comment: @Riggs. yes. it is just linear in each argument.

Answer (score 3):

A [bilinear map](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Bilinear_map) is a special case of [multilinear maps](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Multilinear_map)

To say that $f$ is bilinear means that:

1. $f(\alpha x+\beta y,z)=\alpha f(x,y)+\beta f(y,z)$ and
2. $f(a,\alpha b+\beta c)=\alpha f(a,b)+\beta f(a,c)$

For $x,y,a\in V$ and $z,b,c\in U$ where $U,V$ are vector spaces over a field, $F$ and $\alpha,\beta\in F$

---

You can find examples online, but here are a few.

**First:**

> [Any inner product is a bilinear form](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Inner_product) (this includes the familiar dot-product)

**Second**

> Any $n\times n$ matrix is a bilinear form if you consider it as: $M(x,y)=x^TMy$

Comment: he is asking for examples instead of definition

Comment: @SiXUlm hold please

Comment: @SiXUlm see edits. Although I do think providing examples of things one should search online for isn't something we should be doing

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted your answer accordingly. I agree with your point.

Comment: I had searched online for trivial specific examples that would illustrate the idea and I didn't find any...everything was too abstract. What I found were definitions and abstract examples, hence why I posted this question. I appreciate the edit to include examples.

Comment: So bilinear forms are functions of two variables that are in some sense linear and they are analogous to linear functions of one variable, is that the general idea?

Comment: Yes. @Riggs$\text{    }$

Answer (score 1):

- An inner product over the real numbers is a positive-definite symmetric bilinear form. Since we define $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb R$ and it holds the properties

$$\langle u + v, w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$$

and $$\langle \alpha u , v\rangle = \alpha \langle u,v\rangle$$

for any $u,v,w \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

- Given real-valued functions $f: E \to \mathbb R$ and $g : F \to \mathbb R$ and the function $b : E \times F \to \mathbb R$ defined as $b (u,v) = f(u)g(v)$ is also a bilinear form known as tensor product. Particularly, if $E = F$ then for $f,g: E \to \mathbb R$

$$(f \cdot g) (u,v) = f(u)g(v) + f(v)g(u)$$
and

$$(f \wedge g)(u,v) = f(u)g(v) - f(v)g(u)$$

are bilinear forms, the first symmetric, the second anti-symmetric.

Comment: I like this answer but I sense it goes above what the OP wants or will understand - love the tensor examples, not a chance OP will get them

Comment: The inner product covers the "understandable" part, I guess.